# Timestamp difference between every consecutive row BIGQUERY SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in SQL BQ with ID and DateTime (TIMESTAMP) columns. I want to **calculate the difference in timestamp in let's say seconds between every consecutive row**, and create a new column with calculated time differences.

Table:

```
ID     DateTime
a      2019-10-15 10:00:19 UTC
a      2019-10-15 10:00:29 UTC
a      2019-10-15 10:00:39 UTC
a      2019-10-15 10:00:49 UTC
a      2019-10-15 10:00:59 UTC

the desired result would look like this:

ID     DateTime                    TimeDiff
a      2019-10-15 10:00:19 UTC      null
a      2019-10-15 10:00:29 UTC       10
a      2019-10-15 10:00:39 UTC       10
a      2019-10-15 10:00:49 UTC       10
a      2019-10-15 10:00:59 UTC       10
```

So far i have tried these options with no success:

```
select ID, DateTime,
(LAG(DateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateTime ASC) - DateTime) AS TimeDiff
from `xxx.yyy.table` 
order by DateTime
```

and

```
select ID, DateTime,
timestamp_diff(lag(DateTime, 1) OVER (ORDER BY DateTime)) as TimeDiff
from `xxx.yyy.table`
order by DateTime
```

and

```
select ID, DateTime,
LAG(DateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY FieldID ORDER BY DateTime ASC) AS timeDiff
from `xxx.yyy.table` 
order by DateTime
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LAG()` is the right function to get the value from the previous row.  You just need to use [`TIMESTAMP_DIFF()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff) correctly:

```
select ID, DateTime,
       timestamp_diff(DateTime,
                      lag(DateTime, 1) OVER (ORDER BY DateTime), 
                      second
                     ) as TimeDiff
from `xxx.yyy.table`
order by DateTime;
```

Note that it looks like you want this *per `id`*.  If so, you should `PARTITION BY`  as well:

```
       timestamp_diff(DateTime,
                      lag(DateTime, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DateTime), 
                      second
                     ) as TimeDiff
```